# Add values of a column and display added result in new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

[The table with the data that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqPMp.png)

In the above table I have the columns : weekNumber , weeklyHours ,     points_Rewarded.

There are four employees : a,b,c,d

I have the values for week1,week2,week3, and so on ( I can have data for many more weeks also such as week4,week5, etc)

I want to write a query such that after passing the query I get the total of the **weeklyHours** and **points_Rewarded** for **each** employee in a new table.
The kind of table that the query should give me is here [the desired table that I want  after passing the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy9XN.png)

Please help me with the query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to achieve aggregate values. In your case your are looking for `SUM`.

Try this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(EmployeeID INT, EmployeeName VARCHAR(100),WeekNumber VARCHAR(100),WeeklyHours INT,pointsRewarded INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'a','week1',10,20)
,(2,'b','week1',1,20)
,(3,'c','week1',20,20)
,(4,'d','week1',30,30)
,(1,'a','week2',11,10)
,(2,'b','week2',44,10)
,(3,'c','week2',5,10)
,(4,'d','week2',6,40)
,(1,'a','week3',7,10)
,(2,'b','week3',88,10)
,(3,'c','week3',9,10)
,(4,'d','week3',0,10);

SELECT tbl.EmployeeID
      ,tbl.EmployeeName
      ,SUM(tbl.WeeklyHours) AS Total_Weekly_Hours
      ,SUM(pointsRewarded) AS Total_Points
FROM @tbl AS tbl
GROUP BY tbl.EmployeeID, tbl.EmployeeName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.forgot to mention ,I have an Employee_Id column too.What if I want to insert the Employee_id column in the result

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
      SELECT EmployeeName
           ,SUM (weeklyHours)Total_weekly_hours
           ,SUM (pointsrewarded) TotalPoints 
       FROM YourTable 
     Group By EmployeeName
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `GROUP BY`. You want to group the employees by name so specify employeename in the `GROUP BY` statement. Then just select HOW you want to group the other columns. In this case, you want to `SUM`them:

```
SELECT employeename, 
SUM(weeklyhours) as total_weekly_hours, 
SUM(points_rewarded) as total_points
GROUP BY employeename
```

Note that you could also use `AVG` or `MIN` or `MAX` in place of `SUM` depending on what you want to find. The `AS` clause specifies what you want to call a particular column in your output.

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a96f